# How to render only items searched from a list of <li> elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of li elements that is being passed down to one of my components. These are being rendered in the component. I have a search bar in the same component. I want to be able to only render the items that match what is written down in the search bar. This is what my component looks like.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import LikeBtn from './LikeBtn'

class SearchForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      newList: []
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })

  }



  render() {
    let list = this.props.listProp.map(item => <li className="listItem" key={item.id}><NavLink style={{ color: 'white' }} to={`activities/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</NavLink><LikeBtn /></li>)
    let newList = list.filter(item => item.innerText === this.state.search)
    console.log(newList)

    return (
    <>
      <input type="text" name='search' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      <ul>
        {list}
      </ul>
    </>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchForm
```

I don't know how to get that filtered out so that I can render the items. I tried doing innerText but since I have a LikeBtn component in the li element my filter doesn't work. How else would I be able to implement this? Are there more efficient ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your data and not grab something you've already rendered on screen.

```
render() {
  let filteredList = this.state.search
    ? this.props.listProp.filter((item) =>
        item.name.includes(this.state.search),
      )
    : this.props.listProp;

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" name="search" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <ul>
        {filteredList.map((item) => (
          <li className="listItem" key={item.id}>
            <NavLink style={{ color: 'white' }} to={`activities/${item.id}`}>
              {item.name}
            </NavLink>
            <LikeBtn />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

There is also a snippet below that you can run:

```js
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: '',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    let filteredList = this.state.search
      ? this.props.listProp.filter((item) =>
          item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
        )
      : this.props.listProp;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <input type="search" name="search" autocomplete="off" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <ul>
          {filteredList.map((item) => (
            <li className="listItem" key={item.id}>
              <a href={`activities/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</a>
              <button>Like</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Congress, The',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Glen or Glenda',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Don't Drink the Water",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Blind',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Sirocco',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Sunset Strip',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Better Living',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: '4:44 Last Day on Earth',
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'The Heavy',
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Dr. Who and the Daleks',
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    name: 'Legend of Hell House, The',
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Exit Humanity',
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    name: 'Young in Heart, The',
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: 'Soul Kitchen',
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    name: 'Accattone',
  },
];

ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm listProp={data} />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move this part

```
let list = this.props.listProp.map(item => <li className="listItem" key={item.id}><NavLink style={{ color: 'white' }} to={`activities/${item.id}`}>{item.name}</NavLink><LikeBtn /></li>)
```

to the return and filter the listProp on handleChange.

You can refer to this codeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filter-list-ukef5?file=/src/list.js) for a working sample